# bitwise OR on strings

Tags: c++, string, bit-manipulation

How can i do a Bitwise OR on strings?

```
A:
10001
01010
------
11011
```

Why on strings?
The Bits can have length of 40-50.Maybe this could be problematic on int ?
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean you have two strings where each char is a 0 or a 1?

Comment: _Don't_ use a string just because you need a container. A string is a particular kind of container. For general purposes you have std::vector, std::list, std::set, or as Neil says, std::bitset.

Comment: You already got good answer to this problem the last time you asked it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540742

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say `std::bitset` is more than enough for your situation, but for more flexibility you can use `boost::dynamic_bitset`. Here is an example on `std::bitset`:

```
const size_t N = 64;
string a_str = "10001", b_str = "01010";
bitset<N> a(a_str), b(b_str);
bitset<N> c = a | b;

cout << c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the C++ `std::bitset` class, which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `vector` of `int` values? Doesn't the `bitset` still use a byte per bit?

You can also use a `vector` of `bool` values, but this is also implementation specific.

Depending on whether you need storage efficiency or speed (or the utility of container methods that a couple of these approaches lack) you might profile to decide which approach to use.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also, answers should not be questions.

Comment: Isn't `bitset` implementation specific?

Comment: After a brief Google search, others seem to claim that bitset is not part of the STL standard, and that it does not follow STL container conventions. I'm sure it is a workable option, though.

Comment: Others can claim away - it is part of the C++ Standard - see section 23.3.5 describing it.

Comment: @Neil @Alex bitset is part of the C++ Standard but as far as I can tell there's no specification of how it's stored, using a byte (or even an int) per bit seems legit.

Comment: @andreas The storage is not specified, but no-one would use the thing if it did not in fact store individual bits. That's one reason why they are fixed-sized.

Comment: I have used vectors of `int` and `bool` values in the past, but the use of `bool` vectors is also implementation specific. So probably the best thing to do is profile different approaches, and use whichever is faster or more memory efficient for that platform.

Comment: @Alex I think you are using a specialmeaning of the term "implementation specific". vector <bool> is also standardised (unfortunately, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

For each `char`:

```
char result = (a - '0') | (b - '0') + '0';
```

Where `a` and `b` are two chars with ascii character 0 or 1 in them.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Andreas Brinck's answer, only it returns a full output string and can compare strings of different (arbitrary) lengths.

**Example in C#** (not near c++ compiler right now), but it should be simple to convert it to a language of your choice.

```
public static string BitwiseOr(string input1, string input2)
{
    char[] inarr1 = (char[])input1.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray();
    char[] inarr2 = (char[])input2.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray();
    char[] outarr = new char[input1.Length > input2.Length ? input1.Length : input2.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < outarr.Length ; i++)
    {
        char c1 = i < input1.Length ? inarr1[i] : '0';
        char c2 = i < input2.Length ? inarr2[i] : '0';
        outarr[i] = (char)((c1 - '0') | (c2 - '0') + '0');
    }

    return new string((char[])outarr.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Of course this is only valid if you really need it to be in a string, if not you should (as suggested in other answers) use a vector or similar data type.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of not being C++.